# Angular 6 Search bar and Result two different non-related components

Tags: angular, rest, search

I have two components 
`1. Header Component`
`2. Result Component`
In the header, I have a search bar with a button on click of that I want the result to populate on the result page.

Second problem is once I am the result page if I enter the search value in the header component search it should not reload the page

Both header and result components are not related so I can use `@input` or `output` correct me if there a way for me to pass value?

**main.component.html**

```
  <app-header *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()"></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

**Header.component.html**

```
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/statupdate">Status Update</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/add">Add New</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/projects">Opportunity</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="ClientName" aria-label="Search"
          formControlName="searchText">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Header.component.ts**

```
    this.router.navigate(['search'], {
      queryParams: {
        search: this.searchForm.value.searchText,
      }
    });
  }
```

I have all my result from the search box to display on the result page so i am using router to navigate.
**Result component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,public projectService: ProjectService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.projectService.list(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('search')).subscribe(
          (resp) => {
            this.list = resp;
          },(err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        )
    }
```

Is it possible to populate to data without reloading the page? I am not able to find an example of this

**Update** I have written the BehaviorSubject service to resolve this issue

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(<any>[]);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpService) { }

  changeMessage(message) {

    this.httpClient.get('project?clientName=' + message)
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          this.messageSource.next(resp);
        }
      )
  }
```

but wanted to known if i can improve this coding somewhat like this if possible

```
changeMessage(message) {

    let temp = this.httpClient.get('project?clientName=' + message)
     this.messageSource.next(temp);
  }
```

my **Result.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchService.currentMessage.subscribe(
      (message) => { console.log(message); this.message = message }, (err) => { console.log(err) })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service**

When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should you a shared service. When you have data that should aways been in sync, I find the RxJS BehaviorSubject very useful in this situation.

You can also use a regular RxJS Subject for sharing data via the service, but here’s why I prefer a BehaviorSubject.

1. It will always return the current value on subscription - there is no need to 
   call onnext
2. It has a getValue() function to extract the last value as raw data.
3. It ensures that the component always receives the most recent data.

In the service, we create a private BehaviorSubject that will hold the current value of the message. We define a currentMessage variable handle this data stream as an observable that will be used by the components. Lastly, we create function that calls next on the BehaviorSubject to change its value.

The parent, child, and sibling components all receive the same treatment. We inject the DataService in the constructor, then subscribe to the currentMessage observable and set its value equal to the message variable.

Now if we create a function in any one of these components that changes the value of the message. when this function is executed the new data it’s automatically broadcast to all other components.

```js
data.service.ts
------------------------

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}

one.component.ts
-----------------------------

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}


two.component.ts
--------------------------------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }

}
```